# Ubuntu 18.04 terminal is not responding

Tags: command-line, 18.04, gnome-terminal

When I open gnome-terminal, I see no command prompt. Pressing any button does not help. What can I do to fix my terminal?

[image: screen photo]

Comment: Not sure if that is still (pre)installed, but can you search for `xterm` in your applications as an alternative terminal emulator? If that one works and gives you a usable shell with command prompt, something is badly configured in gnome-terminal, if both don't respond it's likely something bad in your shell initialization scripts. You should probably also be able to run commands from Gnome when you press Alt+F2, can you try opening a different shell in those terminals, by typing `gnome-terminal -e sh` or `xterm -e sh` there respectively? Please report back with the results.

Comment: Btw, Ubuntu 18.04 or 18.10? There is no 18.14 version.

Comment: Run `cp --backup /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and try again, this will reset your `.bashrc` file to the default one.

Comment: check your .bashrc and any included files for incorrect escaping (seems like something is stuck, for example, it could be an alias with incorrect quotes). It should be enough to rename your .bashrc to test whether it is the culprit.

Comment: The wallpaper reveals that it's Ubuntu 18.04 (Bionic Beaver).

Answer (score 1):

Under these circumnstances to be able to edit the `.bashrc`:

1. Go to the terminal and go to Edit/Preferences/Commands:

   Tick these 2 :

   - Run command as a login shell
   - Run a custom command instead of my shell

     - Custom command: `/bin/dash`
2. Close and open a new tab in the terminal, you should have a $ and
       be able to run some basic commands
3. Now you can edit your `.bashrc` file (in your home directory), copy the content to `.bashrc_bad` and then preferably delete everything inside `.bashrc`
4. Save it and run `bash` to see if it crashes again