# Ubuntu 20.04 terminal has no prompt after setting up node for setting up Angular environment

Tags: command-line, 20.04, gnome-terminal, nodejs

When I open terminal, I see no prompt. Pressing any button does not help. I have seen [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1111637/ubuntu-18-04-terminal-is-not-responding), but no solution works as I can't enter commands at all. Terminal is just there, doing nothing.

[image: terminal having no prompt]

I installed `node` and basic commands to install `angular-cli`. I setup my project and ran `npm install`. `ng serve` was the last command when the problem happened.

What can I do to fix my terminal?

Comment: Did the terminal ever work?

Comment: yes. I was setting up environment for angular when this happened.

Comment: OK so please post the exact commands and or steps you did to setup this app. Add them and this info to the question with edit. With out all the details very hard to help you.

Comment: try using xterm

Answer (score 2):

Faced the same issue on **Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS** after installing **ng-common** package and doing some npm build/ install/ run commands.

The part of my `.bash_history` file before I've faced the issue:

```
npm run build
ng
sudo apt install ng-common
npm run build
ls
sudo npm run build
npm run build
npm start
npm run build .
npm install
npm start
npm run build
npm start
```

As I discovered, the issue lied in `.bashrc` file that had the following lines:

```
# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

It turned out that I've enabled CLI autocompletion during `npm run build` and `.bashrc` was updated by **ng-common** package appropriately. Remove the line from `.bashrc` to get your terminal working.

**P.S.** In order to edit `.bashrc` file you may use either [root shell in safe mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92556/how-do-i-boot-into-a-root-shell) or you may edit the file using text editor in GUI.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. Go to your `Home` directory.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>.
3. Edit the `.bashrc` file and delete (or comment out using `#` in front of them) these lines:

   ```
   # Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
   source <(ng completion script)
   ```

Good luck!