# Ubuntu Terminal not working, How to solve it?

Tags: command-line, 22.04

For 10 hours I haven't been able to use my terminal. I have just updated google chrome. Below is the attached image. Today I just updated google chrome. Thanks for help.
[I looked for a solution but it didn't work for me](https://ostechnix.com/how-to-boot-into-rescue-mode-or-emergency-mode-in-ubuntu-18-04/)

[image: Image of broken terminal]

Comment: There are numerous causes for what you describe, most are the result of changes made by the owner (*such as changing the default python3 version but that's only one example*), so providing details as to what was done before this occurred may help (esp. the last session before this problem appeared)

Comment: Can you log in to a text screen (with the hotkey combination ctrl + alt + F3)? In that case, do you get a working terminal behaviour?

Comment: It looks like your *terminal* is working, but the shell inside it isn't - the most common reason we see for that is that you have added a long-running or non-terminating command to its startup file(s) (most often, `~/.bashrc`)

Comment: @steeldriver or the properties of the default terminal session have been modified and the session does not run a proper shell

Comment: @jtessier72 Does this solve your problem? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438682/ubuntu-20-04-terminal-is-not-responding

Comment: @raj - I'm editor, not the one who asked the question :)

Comment: @raj  yess thank to all. It is solved by following this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438682/ubuntu-20-04-terminal-has-no-prompt-after-setting-up-node-for-setting-up-angular

Comment: Thank to all
Solved by following this [enter link description here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438682/ubuntu-20-04-terminal-has-no-prompt-after-setting-up-node-for-setting-up-angular)