# Cannot control terminal after installing Node

Tags: 22.04, gnome-terminal, nodejs

I can no longer control my Ubuntu 22.04 terminal. The terminal asks me to install `ng-common` and then I can't use the terminal. This is how my terminal currently looks like:

[image: current terminal]

I was trying to install Node via NVM because I need to use Angular. Then in the command line I saw a warning saying that "Angular is not compatible with the node installer version", and so after installing Node 20.10.0 with NVM, I got a line in the console (`apt get install ng-common`).

I no longer have more details because I restarted my computer thinking it was a crash problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 terminal has no prompt after setting up node for setting up Angular environment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1438682/ubuntu-20-04-terminal-has-no-prompt-after-setting-up-node-for-setting-up-angular)

Answer (score 2):

It's working now. I have removed in `~/.bashrc` these lines:

```bash
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion


# Load Angular CLI autocompletion.
source <(ng completion script)
```

<sup>Answer moved here from [OP's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1493692/cannot-control-terminal-after-installing-node#comment2617016_1493692).</sup>